# Copy and share Google Doc with the same people

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Hi I am trying to copy a template and want it to be shared with the same people (similar to how we do it manually). I am a total noob and get by with just doing the basic stuff, so I am not able to fix

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Create My Checklist');
  menu.addItem('New Checklist', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //id of the document template
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1qRQ07PDmz1il9IftM9GIJfY37vTusfQZhhNS1BRELJQ');
  
  //id of the folder where the completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1JufckhwXlAXDAE3_-f60lHQQ-jqe9Mx1')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
  
  //get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //check if this row is the headers, if yes, skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if yes, skip it
    if (row[10]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, make a copy of the template document in the destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy("My Checklist - " + row[2] + " - " + row[4] + " - " +  row[5], destinationFolder)
    //Copy, then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //Get contents for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    
    //replace token with values from spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{Employee ID}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Level}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{Department}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Business Unit}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{Location}}', row[6]);
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 11).setValue(url)
    
  })}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to share the copied file of `const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy("My Checklist - " + row[2] + " - " + row[4] + " - " +  row[5], destinationFolder)` with other users.

  - `the same people (similar to how we do it manually)` means `share with the same people`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
//Start processing each spreadsheet row
rows.forEach(function(row, index){
  //check if this row is the headers, if yes, skip it
  if (index === 0) return;
  //check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if yes, skip it
  if (row[10]) return;
  //Using the row data in a template literal, make a copy of the template document in the destinationFolder
  const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy("My Checklist - " + row[2] + " - " + row[4] + " - " +  row[5], destinationFolder)
  //Copy, then open it using the DocumentApp
```

#### To:

```js
const emailAddresses = googleDocTemplate.getEditors().map(e => e.getEmail()); // Added

//Start processing each spreadsheet row
rows.forEach(function(row, index){
  //check if this row is the headers, if yes, skip it
  if (index === 0) return;
  //check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if yes, skip it
  if (row[10]) return;
  //Using the row data in a template literal, make a copy of the template document in the destinationFolder
  const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy("My Checklist - " + row[2] + " - " + row[4] + " - " +  row[5], destinationFolder)

  copy.addEditors(emailAddresses); // Added

  //Copy, then open it using the DocumentApp
```

- From your question, I couldn't understand whether you wanted to share the file as the editor. So if you wanted to share it with the viewer, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      copy.addEditors(emailAddresses);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      copy.addViewers(emailAddresses);
    ```

#### References:

- [addEditors(emailAddresses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditorsemailaddresses)
- [addViewers(emailAddresses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addviewersemailaddresses)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike.

Does this mean that I have to add the email addresses manually in the script? 

const emailAddresses = ["email address 1", "email address 2",,,];

The template is shared with a few team's owners who will eventually sign off in the document and the owners can change. The idea is to add editors to the template document and when I make a copy, i would select the 'share with the same people' checkbox.

Comment: @Shamie Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, now I understood `same people`. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: thank you so much, this worked perfectly!

Comment: @Shamie Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I have a follow-up question on the sharing edit access. Now that I have the new document shared with the same people, If i would like to also share with someone new, and their email is in the first row of my google sheet, how do i do it?

`copy.addEditors( row[0]);`

Would this work?

Comment: @Shamie About your new question, I would like to support you. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do about your new question. So can you provide detailed information about your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, My initial ask was to share it with the same people. The code you have edited works well.

However, when we copy the document to create a new file, on top of sharing with the same people, i would also like to share with another person to edit it. The email of the person who can edit is in the google sheet, in column A.

Comment: @Shamie Thank you for replying. About your new question, I would like to support you. But from your replying, I think that the issue of replying is new question, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, understood. I have posted as a new question.

Comment: @Shamie From `thank you so much, this worked perfectly!` in your replying, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation.